# How do I format the array for updating an issue through the Rest API in Drupal?

Tags: php, api, drupal, rest, redmine

I want to add a note on a Redmine issue. I am using Drupal and PHP for this.

I can fetch data and post issues so I know connectivity to Redmine through the API is fine.

I have had a look at the documentation for the Redmine API at http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api

At the bottom for issue creation it gives a format of the following:

```
PUT /issues/[id].json
{
"issue": {
  "subject": "Example issue (was: Test issue)",
  "notes": "Changing the subject" 
}
}
```

Now when I create an issue for example, the array is a simple one dimensional one. What is the structure for the array of data which I need to pass for this issue updating process.

Example of my issue creation array:

```
$redmineIssueArray = array();
$redmineIssueArray['project_id'] = 2;
$redmineIssueArray['subject'] = $typeBug . " $date";
$redmineIssueArray['priority_id'] = 4;
$redmineIssueArray['description'] = $bugDesc;
$redmineIssueArray['assigned_to_id'] = 2;
```

Just a note, the function to update an issue from the redmine module in Drupal is:

```
redmine_rest_api_issue_update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to use Drupal functions, use [PHPActiveResource](https://github.com/lux/phpactiveresource) and updating an issue will be easy like:

```
// find and update an issue
$issue->find(2);
echo $issue->subject;
$issue->set('subject', 'This is the new subject')->save ();
// update status
$issue->set('status_id', 2)->save();
```